# Как сделать 2 запроса в rx java?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Есть 2 сервиса.Независимые у и каждого свои модели ответа.
Надо послать запрос в сервис А проверить модель ответа на наличие юзера и если есть юзер послать запрос Б .
Как можно красиво сделать это с помощью `rxJava`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Observable.fromCallable{ service1.getUser() }
    .filter { user -> user.isValid() }
    .flatMap { user -> Observable.fromCallable { service2.getData(user) }}
```

Comment: а если в фильтре будет ошибка ?0

Comment: ошибка где угодно может быть, ее можно обработать в subscribe либо оператором, в вопросе этого не было.

Comment: в конце .subscribe({data -> ???}, {error -> ???})